# Зачем нужен html хелпер

Tags: yii2

Зачем в yii сделали html хелпер?
В каких ситуациях его лучше использовать, чем нативный html код.
Например, activeForm помимо формы добавляет скрытое поле с токеном для безопасности, который мы просто так узнать не можем. А хелпер зачем?

Comment: если так посудить, то любой функционал Yii2 это всего лишь набор определённого кода на языке, GridView тоже можно не использовать, а сделать самому таблицу на HTML и прикрутить к ней сортировки :)

Comment: https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-helper-html.html вот тут можно почитать, что есть в этом helper'е, его ведь никто и не заставляет использовать, этим и хорош framework: не хочешь - не используй

Comment: Из ссылки MasterAlex - "Если ваша разметка близка к статической, лучше использовать непосредственно HTML. Нет никакой необходимости в том, чтобы всё подряд оборачивать вызовами Html-помощника."

Answer (score 1):

Отвечая на вопрос зачем* можно сказать, что helper ы созданы для того ,чтобы ускорить написания кода, их можно использовать или нет, решать вам. 
Во первых повышается читабельность кода, вы видите хелпер , параеметры и сразу понимаете, что зачем и куда.
Во вторых количество написанных строк кода уменьшается, то есть вы больше занимаетесь логикой приложения, нежели физическим повторением написания 
 одного и того же кода
Вот пример :

```
<?= Html::dropDownList('list', $currentUserId, ArrayHelper::map($userModels, 'id', 'name')) ?>
```

или helper Url к примеру, который избавляет вас от того, чтобы заморачиваться, правильность написания относительных или обсалютных путей, вставил alias и уже половина готова...

Я думаю мысль вы уловили.
Кстати по поводу форм, очень часто встречал проекты где разработчики не использовали field в actveform. Каждый использует возможности по своему желанию